# npm shrinkwrap captures peerDependencies of devDependencies

Tags: node.js, npm

We're using `npm shrinkwrap` to lock down our production deps. It's excluding `devDeps` as intended (and documented) but modules that are `peerDependencies` of those only are still being included.

Is there any way I can exclude those without having to clone the repo elsewhere and run `npm install -p` before shinkwrapping?